# Changing the format of citation fields

Tags: biblatex, biber

I a `beamer` presentation I want to print citations in the footnotes of the respective slides where they are mentioned + a full bibliography at the end. After some research on tex.stackexchange I am currently using the `authortitle` style with some modifications.

Unfortunately, the modifications are not completely behaving the way I would like them to behave. This is my `MWE`:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}

\begin{filecontents*}{tmp_bib.bib} 
@book{Peter1, 
    author={Peter Muller}, 
    title={My life as Peter Mueller}, 
    address={Peterstown}, 
    publisher={Petersen family},
    year={2017}
} 
@article{Klaus1,
    author = {Peter, Klaus and Petersen, Peter},
    title = {A research article about Peter Mueller},
    journal = {Intern. Journal on Science},
    year = {2018},
    volume = {33},
    pages = {000007},
    doi = {10.10}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage[
    style=authortitle,
    autocite=footnote,
    backend=biber,
    ]
    {biblatex}
\addbibresource{tmp_bib.bib}

\renewbibmacro*{cite:title}{%
  \ifentrytype{article}{
    \printtext[bibhyperref]{%
      \printfield{journaltitle}%
      \setunit{\space}%
      \printtext[parens]{\printdate}%
    }
  }{}%
  \ifentrytype{book}{
    \printtext[bibhyperref]{%
      \printfield[citetitle]{labeltitle}%
      \setunit{\space}%
      \printtext[parens]{\printdate}%
    }%
  }{}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[t]{One column on this page}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item Even more text\footnotemark
    \footcitetext{Peter1}
        \item Note: an article\footnotemark
    \footcitetext{Klaus1}
    \end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Bibliography}
    \printbibliography
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

It results in the following slide: [image: references in footnote] 
It looks fine, except for one thing: I want the journal title to *not* be italic. How do I change this?

In addition, how do I add the journal volume in bold text to the article?

Comment: For a general-purpose introduction into `biblatex` modifications, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12806/35864. Though in this case one would have to know which field formats control which output, so `biblatex.def` and `standard.bbx` are an essential source of information here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change it for `journaltitle` with:

```
\DeclareFieldFormat{journaltitle}{#1}
```

As for the journal volume, something a little *ad hoc*, but in line with it appearing in the citation in a `authortitle` style, would be to include it in your modified `cite:title` bibmacro:

```
\printfield[citevolume]{volume}
```

for which you should also declare the corresponding formatting directive.

In full:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}

\begin{filecontents*}{tmp_bib.bib}
@book{Peter1,
    author={Peter Muller},
    title={My life as Peter Mueller},
    address={Peterstown},
    publisher={Petersen family},
    year={2017}
}
@article{Klaus1,
    author = {Peter, Klaus and Petersen, Peter},
    title = {A research article about Peter Mueller},
    journal = {Intern. Journal on Science},
    year = {2018},
    volume = {33},
    pages = {000007},
    doi = {10.10}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage[
    style=authortitle,
    autocite=footnote,
    backend=biber,
    ]
    {biblatex}
\addbibresource{tmp_bib.bib}

\renewbibmacro*{cite:title}{%
  \ifentrytype{article}{%
    \printtext[bibhyperref]{%
      \printfield{journaltitle}%
      \setunit{\addspace}%
      \printfield[citevolume]{volume}%
      \setunit{\addspace}%
      \printtext[parens]{\printdate}%
    }%
  }{}%
  \ifentrytype{book}{%
    \printtext[bibhyperref]{%
      \printfield[citetitle]{labeltitle}%
      \setunit{\space}%
      \printtext[parens]{\printdate}%
    }%
  }{}%
}

\DeclareFieldFormat{journaltitle}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat{citevolume}{\mkbibbold{#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[t]{One column on this page}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item Even more text\footnotemark
    \footcitetext{Peter1}
        \item Note: an article\footnotemark
    \footcitetext{Klaus1}
    \end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Bibliography}
    \printbibliography
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]